# Application Insights Rate Limit Exceeded - Check Origin Of Requests

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

We are using Application Insights in our application for monitoring purposes.

Today we received a message, that we exceeded the  rate limit of 86,400 requests per day (https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization/Rate-limits).

To analyze the cause of the problem I would like to know the origin of those requests. Is it possible to do this either in the azure portal or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can examine requests/dependencies/other documents in Application Insights Analytics and check from their content who sent them.

```
union *
| order by timestamp
| take 1000
```